# Clarification on Borel Cantelli theorem, part 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am having troubles in understanding a part of the proof of the part $1$ Borel Cantelli lemma.

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ a probability space and $(A_n)$ a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$.
> $$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} P(A_n) < +\infty \implies P(\limsup_{n\to +\infty} A_n) = 0$$

**Proof**

According to my notes:

We recall that $\limsup_n A_n = \cap_k \cup_{n\geq k} A_n$. Thus we have $\omega \in\limsup_n A_n$ iff $\omega$ appears in infinitely many of the $A_n$.
This shows we have $\limsup_n A_n = \{ \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n} = +\infty\}$.

Via Beppo Levi Theorem we have:

$$\int\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n} dP = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \int \mathbb{1}_{A_n} dP = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} P(A_n) < +\infty$$

Now since $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n} < +\infty$ almost everywhere, then   $P(\limsup_{n\to +\infty} A_n) = 0 follows.

**What I don't understand**

Principally, this: "since $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n} < +\infty$ almost everywhere, then..."

It's not clear to me why this is true and how we got this.

Also, some clarification about the statement

"$\omega \in\limsup_n A_n$ iff $\omega$ appears in infinitely many of the $A_n$.
This shows we have $\limsup_n A_n = \{ \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{1}_{A_n} = +\infty\}$"

what is $\omega$? What does this really tell me?

Thank you!

Comment: Since $\sum 1_{A_n}$ has a finite integral with respect to the probability measure $P$, it has to be finite $P$-a.e. (otherwise there would exist a measurable set $B$, with $P(B)>0$ and such that $\sum 1_{A_n}(\omega)=+\infty$ for $\omega\in B$, so that $\int_B\sum 1_{A_n}dP=+\infty$, violating the statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\int \sum A_n dP < \infty $ that means the integrand is finite almost everywhere (otherwise we would have $\int \sum A_n dP = \infty$).

$\omega$ is one of the possible out comes from the sample space $\Omega$. The fact that $\omega \in \limsup A_n = \cap_n \cup_{k \geq n} A_k$ means that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (the intersection part) there is some $k \geq n$ so that $\omega \in A_k$ (the union part). This is equivalent to that $\omega  \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now if $\omega \in A_n$ for infinitely many (i.e. $\omega \in \limsup A_n)$ then $\sum_n 1_{A_n}(\omega) = \infty$  since $1_{A_n} (\omega) = 1$ for everytime $\omega \in A_n$, which is infinitely many times. So $\limsup A_n = \{ \omega \in \Omega : \sum_n 1_{A_n}(\omega) = \infty \}$

Comment: Thank you! That was clear indeed!

Comment: Just a question: how can $k \geq n$? I have a different definition of lim sup

Comment: @Numb3rs it is the same definition as yours, I just switched the k and n. Sorry for the confusion!